# Choghadiya for extreme places like Antarctica

Tags: muhurta

Since the Choghadiya are based on Sunrise and Sunset for each day, how are they calculated for extreme places like Antarctica where the sun doesn’t set for 6 months?

Comment: It will be calculated as it is. Because of such a position the time intervals will be expectionally longer than places near equator.

Comment: @Proxy so do you mean that each Choghadiya would be multiple weeks long?

Comment: Yes, because it only takes account of sun rise and sun sets. That is why it's described differently for different geographical locations.

Comment: Take a look for the choghadiya of Fairbanks, Alaska as on the longest day of 21 June 2021, with 22 hours of daylight. https://www.drikpanchang.com/muhurat/choghadiya.html?date=21/06/2021